# Add parameter as drop down list in ADF pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have a Copy Data task which is obtaining data from an API

I want to add the Request Method as a parameter to be defined at run time so I want it to be a Drop Down list instead of a String, Can this be done in Azure Data Factory?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, It is not possible to create dropdown list for Request Method.

But you can raise feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c)

Refere - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http?tabs=data-factory